# How do I read a text file into an arraylist, excluding lines that contain certain words?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make a program that reads a text file named `text.txt` into an `ArrayList`. And then after that it must remove any lines of the text that contain the words "I love cake"

So say this is the text from the file:

```
I love cake so much
yes i do
I love cake
I dont care
```

Here is my code. I have it reading the file but I don't understand how I can remove certain lines (the ones that contain "I love cake").

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Cake {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File fileIn = new File("text.txt");
        ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner s= new Scanner(fileIn);    
        String line;

        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            line = s.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since your are reading lines as strings you can use String.matches() to exclude some, for example: if (! line.matches("I love cake")  { System.out.println(line); }.  Since String.matches() takes a regex argument, the quality of matching can be improved with regex wildcards, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`String.contains()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-).

Your code would look like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Cake {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File fileIn = new File("text.txt");
        ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(fileIn);
        String line;

        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            line = s.nextLine();

            if(!line.contains("I love cake")){ //If "I love cake" is not in the line
                System.out.println(line); //Then it's ok to print that line
                text.add(line); //And we can add it to the arraylist
            }
        }
        s.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Java8:

```
Path file = new File("text.txt").toPath();
List<String> linesWithoutCake = Files.lines(file)
        .filter(s -> !s.contains("I love cake"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can [continue using the stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) with lines that don't contain your pattern. For example count them:

```
long count = Files.lines(file).filter(s -> !s.contains("I love cake")).count();
```

Comment: This is very spiffy. +1 for the Java 8 one-liner.